# Using CC: Field and/or BCC: field with no To: field, email addresses put in To: field

Tags: vba, outlook

When I assign email addresses to the To:, CC: and BCC: fields, I have to assign the To: field last or it will put the cc or bcc in the To: field.

With the code in this order (To, BCC, CC) -

```
'These have to be 3, 2, 1 or else the BCC: or CC: shows up in the To: field of the email
' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(RecipientList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 1  ' 1 = olTo  
'Add those who are being bcc'd on this email
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(bccList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 3  ' 3 = olBCC 
'Add those who are being cc'd on this email
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(ccList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 2  ' 2 = olCC
```

The email looks like this:

```
To: = cc@cc.com  
CC: = ""  
BCC: = bcc@cc.com
```

With the code in this order (To, CC, BCC)

```
'These have to be 3, 2, 1 or else the BCC: or CC: shows up in the To: field of the email
' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(RecipientList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 1  ' 1 = olTo 
'Add those who are being cc'd on this email
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(ccList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 2  ' 2 = olCC  
'Add those who are being bcc'd on this email
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(bccList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 3  ' 3 = olBCC
```

The email looks like this:

```
To: = bcc@cc.com  
CC: = cc@cc.com  
BCC: = ""
```

With the code in this order (BCC, CC, To)

```
'These have to be 3, 2, 1 or else the BCC: or CC: shows up in the To: field of the email
'Add those who are being bcc'd on this email
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(bccList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 3  ' 3 = olBCC 
'Add those who are being cc'd on this email
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(ccList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 2  ' 2 = olCC 
' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(RecipientList)
objOutlookRecip.Type = 1  ' 1 = olTo
```

The email comes out correctly like this:

```
To: = ""  
CC: = cc@cc.com  
BCC: = bcc@cc.com
```

Also, if I want to send an email with a cc: and/or bcc: without a To:,  I get

> "Error 440: There must be at least one name or contact group in the To, Cc or Bcc box."

I have the other two so why am I getting this error?

I added this piece of code before the other stuff which gets rid of the error:

```
If Len(RecipientList) = 0 Then
    RecipientList = " "
End If
```

This is the calling routine:

```
SendTestHTMLMessages "to@to.com", "cc@cc.com:", "bcc@bcc.com", "Test Message Subject", "Test Message Body"
```

This is the working code:

```
Sub SendTestHTMLMessages(RecipientList As String, Optional ccList As String, Optional bccList As String, Optional Subject As String, Optional Body As String)

    Dim objOutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
    Dim objOutlookMsg As Object ' Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objOutlookRecip As Object ' Outlook.Recipient

    Dim Signature As String

    ' Create the Outlook session.
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    objOutlook.Session.Logon

    ' Create the message.
    Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)   '0 = olMailItem  (Late Binding)

If Len(RecipientList) = 0 Then
    RecipientList = " "
End If

With objOutlookMsg

    'These have to be 3, 2, 1 or else the BCC: or CC: shows up in the To: field of the email
    If Len(bccList) > 0 Then
        'Add those who are being bcc'd on this email
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(bccList)
        objOutlookRecip.Type = 3  ' 3 = olBCC
    End If
    If Len(ccList) > 0 Then
        'Add those who are being cc'd on this email
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(ccList)
        objOutlookRecip.Type = 2  ' 2 = olCC
    End If
    If Len(RecipientList) > 0 Then
        ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add(RecipientList)
        objOutlookRecip.Type = 1  ' 1 = olTo
    End If

    ' Set the Subject & Body of the message.
    .Subject = Subject
    .htmlBody = Body
    '.BodyFormat = 3   '3 = olFormatRichText
    Set .SendUsingAccount = objOutlook.Session.Accounts.Item(1)

    .Display

End With

End Sub
```

This feels kludgy and I would like to be understand why it is acting this way.

Comment: Edit the question using this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The few people willing to generate their own running code could possibly introduce their own errors.

Comment: I made the edit as you suggested. Let me know if there is anything else I need to do to make it easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow `objOutlookRecip.Type =` with `objOutlookRecip.Resolve`

Or `objOutlookMsg.Recipients.ResolveAll` just after `End With`.